# XSL defining complex (non standard) XML attributes for transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have a xml that I am transforming with an XSL template. 
The trouble is that a lot of the attributes stored withinin it that appear to be causing my transform to fail. Is there a way to predefine these attributes/namespace prefixes such that the transform can continue with stopping and me having to manually remove the offending names?

I am using Satimage xmlLib for the transform.

For example :

```
<ConstantValue>
     <Value abc:actualType="Int32">2</Value>
</ConstantValue>
```

or

```
<OperationDefinition abc:uid="urn:uuid:f9ff09d2-cc85-3d29-a982-a8776842dac0">
   <OperationInputCount>2</OperationInputCount>
</OperationDefinition>
```

I also have elements with a colon in the element name which is breaking the transform.

```
 <this:AppCode>14</this:AppCode>
```

For the purposes of my transformation I do no need to keep these attributes,only the values inside the elements.

Many Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by _"outside the standard XML naming convention"_? If you mean `abc:actualType`, that's just a namespace prefix.

Comment: There is no "standard XML naming convention". If you think there is, then you do not understand XML. Please define your question in terms of sample input, expected output, rules of transformation and what version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Do I have to predefine namespace prefix's at the top of the transform? In actual fact I dont want to transform any of the nodes with the abc:uid or abc:actualtype prefixes. The fact is they appear to cause my xsl transform to fail until I manually rename them .

Answer (score 0):

Names with colons are allowed in core XML, but not in XML that is namespace-well-formed, unless the part before the colon is properly declared as a namespace prefix. XSLT and nearly all other modern XML applications require the XML to be namespace-well-formed, so you will not be able to process this XML using XSLT unless you first convert it. You could convert it, for example, by changing all the colons to dots or underscores.